# How to cross-compile llvm/clang for ios simulator?

Tags: ios, clang, cross-compiling

```
export CC="clang -arch i386 -mios-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk"

export CXX="clang++ -arch i386 -mios-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk"

../llvm_34_ios/configure --prefix=/Users/admin/llvm_34_ios_i386_installed --host=i386-apple-darwin11 --enable-optimized --disable-assertions

unset CC CXX

make
```

i'm getting error:

```
llvm[1]: Building Intrinsics.gen.tmp from Intrinsics.td
error:ERROR: Couldn't find the `Intrinsic' class!

make[1]: *** [/Users/admin/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/lib/IR/Release/Intrinsics.gen.tmp] Error 1
```

Comment: No, it will not work on simulator

Comment: For others who may stumble across this in the future, I did get this to work in the end but had to specify `-mios-simulator-version-min=8.0` along with the other flags when exporting `CC` and `CCX`

Comment: can you show your command-line to compile for ios simulator?

Comment: Here's the script I used: https://gist.github.com/SquaredTiki/d5da9d1c1ee78a587c76

Comment: i was able to compile .a for i386 using the script above. Not sure libs are working though.

Comment: This looks like it would be easier if you would create a toolchain file and use cmake rather than trying to convince Make to do what you want