# Unable to cross compile iOS programs on linux

Tags: ios, linux, cross-compiling, gnu, jailbreak

I know that someone already asked this question but it isn`t up to date anymore. Most of the links are dead and the commands are not relevant anymore.

I have read these

[Compile IOS program from linux commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085052/compile-ios-program-from-linux-commandline)

[How to cross-compile clang/llvm for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946851/how-to-cross-compile-clang-llvm-for-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For example, I have been trying to compile silversearcher-ag for my iPhone 6 (jailbroken). This is the project link https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher.

I am targeting iOS 12.4.

These are the commands that I`ve tried

`./configure CC=/home/growtopiajaw/Desktop/cctools-port-master/usage_examples/ios_toolchain/target/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-clang CXX=/home/growtopiajaw/Desktop/cctools-port-master/usage_examples/ios_toolchain/target/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-clang++ --host=arm-apple-darwin11`

`make`

I am using cctools-port to cross compile the project. My compiled cctools toolchain is located under `/home/growtopiajaw/Desktop/cctools-port-master/usage_examples/ios_toolchain/target` and below is how the toolchain`s directory structure looks like
[image: cctools directory structure]

This is my configure log: https://del.dog/nugibonury

This is my make log:

```
CC       src/ignore.o
In file included from src/ignore.c:11:
./src/options.h:7:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include <pcre.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:494: src/ignore.o] Error 1
```

This is my GitHub repository containing the cross compile toolchain
https://github.com/GrowtopiaJaw/arm-apple-darwin11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not ship PCRE. You need to get the headers and dylib/tbd files manually.

If you're using checkra1n or unc0ver, then [the deb on the APT repo](https://apt.bingner.com/debs/1443.00/pcre_8.42-1_iphoneos-arm.deb) contains headers as well, so you could just use that.

If you plan to package this into an APT/dpkg file, make sure to add `pcre` as a dependency.

Comment: Since iOS uses clang and this project is basically built upon gcc, I can’t seems to compile this project on iOS as well. Trying both Clang with LLVM version 5 and Clang version 10, ./configure complains about clang not being able to executable files. This is my configure log https://del.dog/torrimaduj and this is the full config.log https://del.dog/mabangesta

Comment: That is most likely due to your toolchain running out of `/var` - shebangs have been thoroughly crippled by the sandbox. :/

Comment: is there any way to overcome this though either by cross compiling on linux or on the phone itself. I really have no idea what to do anymore

Comment: Yes, cross-compiling is perfectly possible, and it seems you were already trying that anyway. Just download the deb I linked to, extract the `data.tar.lzma` inside it, and either merge the `usr/include` and `usr/lib` folders with your project, or pass them through with `-I` and `-L`.

Comment: yup, thanks. that works. but i was wondering if this could be applied on other projects. it seems that some gcc flags are not available on clang for example -Wlogical-op