# Almost naked iOS8.4 --> how to get a linker?

Tags: ios, linker, clang, llvm, ld

**EDIT 2015-29-10. II.** In fact `-arch armv7` instead of `-arch arm64` and without lowering optimization, worked perfectly.

**EDIT 2015-29-10. I.** I tried to add

```
export CFLAGS="-O1"
export CXXFLAGS="-O1"
```

before `configure`, and had the same error, with a different file missing this time :

```
 "/usr/local/cctools-arm64-port/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch arm64 -iphoneos_version_min 5.0.0 -syslibroot /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -o testcpp /var/tmp/testcpp-4f79ac.o -lstdc++ -lSystem
ld: file not found: N?L
```

I also tried with `-O0` optimization instead of `-01`, same result.

**EDIT 2015-28-10. II.** I did this :

```
./autogen.sh
export CC="clang -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=8.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk"
export CXX="clang++ -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=8.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk"
./configure -v --host=arm-apple-darwin11 --prefix=/usr/local/lvm-cross/cctools-arm64-port
unset CC CXX
make && sudo make install
```

Then I tried a simple hello world on iDevice, with testcpp.cpp containing :

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "oijo" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
clang++ -v -isysroot /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -target arm64-apple-darwin11 testcpp.cpp -o testcpp
```

which gave me :

```
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin11
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/local/llvm-ios/bin/clang++" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-ios5.0.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name testcpp.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi darwinpcs -target-linker-version 253.3.3 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /usr/local/llvm-ios/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0 -isysroot /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /var/mobile/Documents/CODING/MY/TESTS_0/CPP -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 108 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=ios-5.0.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/tmp/testcpp-f1de66.o -x c++ testcpp.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0 default target arm-apple-darwin14.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/arm64-apple-darwin10/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/llvm-ios/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0/include
 /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/usr/include
 /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/local/cctools-arm64-port/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch arm64 -iphoneos_version_min 5.0.0 -syslibroot /usr/local/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -o testcpp /var/tmp/testcpp-f1de66.o -lstdc++ -lSystem
ld: file not found: ?4
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried without the `unset CC CXX`, with the same "success"...

**EDIT 2015-28-10. I.** Using cydia solutions as suggested indeed worked, but I definitely want to build it myself, so I followed the https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port way. As it is way too boring to get/build `libtool` for mac os, I switched to a vitual box ubuntu 15.10 64 bits, where I `sudo apt-get install`'ed the following packages : `automake`, `autogen`, `libtool`, `clang-3.7`, `uuid-dev` and `llvm-3.7-dev`. Then I `cd`'ed to the `cctools` directory and did :

```
./autogen.sh
export CC="clang-3.7 -arch arm64"
export CXX="clang++-3.7 -arch arm64"
./configure --prefix=/home/lvm-ubuntu/Desktop/iPad/cctools-produced/ --host=arm-apple-darwin11
make
```

(The complete output is in the [new following gist.](https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/3ece944fab28be85a04d)) `make` produced the following warnings and errors :

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-arch arm64'

../include/foreign/libkern/arm/OSByteOrder.h:11:10: error: redefinition of
  '_OSSwapInt16'
uint16_t _OSSwapInt16(uint16_t data)
         ^
../include/foreign/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h:46:1: note: previous definition
      is here
_OSSwapInt16(
^
```

and analogue errors for `_OSSwapInt32` and `_OSSwapInt64`... I must be for sure doing something wrong.

---

**Initial question.**

I succeed in cross-building clang+llvm for iOS8.4 on a jailbroken iPad mini 3 wifi, mainly thanks to the two following questions :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808144/how-to-cross-compile-clang-llvm-3-7-0-for-ios8-x-on-ipad-mini-3/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808144/how-to-cross-compile-clang-llvm-3-7-0-for-ios8-x-on-ipad-mini-3/33068628#33068628)

and

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946851/how-to-cross-compile-clang-llvm-for-ios/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946851/how-to-cross-compile-clang-llvm-for-ios/23950039?noredirect=1#comment54201111_23950039)

Set all paths etc, and tried a `clang++ -v testcpp.cpp -o testcpp` where `testcpp.cpp`contains :

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and got this :

```
clang++: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(the whole verbose output is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/ad4e24666fd2883dacb6).)

Obviously I don't have GNU's `ld` nor any real "remplacement" of it (by llvm-clang), so that I am asking myself : what is my strategy in this case ? (Having no linker, I can't even try to build `binutils` on my iPad to use its `ld`).

*Precision* : I would like the linking to be done behind the scene, so that I could keep doing `clang++ -v testcpp.cpp -o testcpp`, that is, I don't want to do the linking "manually" myself in several steps. (But a script could be ok, even if I find more elegant to have a real `ld` replacement...)

*Remark* : in llvm-clang `bin` folder I have this :

```
XXXXs-iPad:/usr/local/llvm-ios/bin mobile$ ls -l
total 274412
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   205456 Oct 18 12:49 FileCheck*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  7704096 Oct 18 12:48 bugpoint*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   122036 Oct 18 12:48 c-index-test*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 40802004 Oct 18 12:48 clang*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 40802004 Oct 18 12:49 clang++*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 31252792 Oct 18 12:49 clang-check*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1225352 Oct 18 12:49 clang-format*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   671500 Oct 18 12:49 clang-tblgen*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel    49684 Oct 18 12:49 count*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 22439396 Oct 18 12:49 llc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 10351388 Oct 18 12:49 lli*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   208140 Oct 18 12:49 lli-child-target*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  9144692 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-ar*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1619592 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-as*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   155080 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-bcanalyzer*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   120864 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-config*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel    92232 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-config-host*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1604600 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-cov*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1472656 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-cxxdump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1471516 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-diff*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1225632 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-dis*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 18342488 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-dsymutil*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   419892 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-dwarfdump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1686496 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-extract*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1800856 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-link*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 10140692 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-mc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   138552 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-mcmarkup*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  9144172 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-nm*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11554352 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-objdump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   220840 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-pdbdump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   469920 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-profdata*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  9144692 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-ranlib*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1768528 Oct 18 12:49 llvm-readobj*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  8388100 Oct 18 12:50 llvm-rtdyld*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1489124 Oct 18 12:50 llvm-size*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  2106052 Oct 18 12:50 llvm-stress*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1610176 Oct 18 12:50 llvm-symbolizer*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1422732 Oct 18 12:50 llvm-tblgen*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1455516 Oct 18 12:50 macho-dump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel    71184 Oct 18 12:50 not*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1620520 Oct 18 12:50 obj2yaml*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 23007212 Oct 18 12:50 opt*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel  1768416 Oct 18 12:50 verify-uselistorder*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   402360 Oct 18 12:50 yaml2obj*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `org.coolstar.cctools` and `org.coolstar.ld64` via Cydia.

Or, alternatively, build https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port by hand.

`CXX="clang++ -arch arm64" CC="clang -arch arm64" ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin11`

Comment: I have already tried the first one which includes the second, without success. I will try to build tpoechtrager's port and will keep you posted.

Comment: Ok, I miss `libtoolize`, `autoconf`, `automake` and `aclocal`, as I am under mac os. I built `autoconf` and `automake` from source, `aclocal` is part of `automake` so it's ok. I managed to find `libtool` that I can build from source, but no `libtoolize` source.

Comment: @user10000100_u: `org.coolstar.ld64` should work anyway, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, it did work indeed with cydia's packages, but now I would like to build linker myself. So I followed instructions [here](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port) under ubuntu 15.10 64bits : I installed llvm-dev, uuid-dev, automake, autogen, libtoo, clang-3.7, and did `export CXX="clang++-3.7 -arch arm64" export CC="clang-3.7 -arch arm64" ./configure --prefix=<...> --host=arm-apple-darwin11`, and got finally error of the following kinds : `error redefinition of OSWriteSwapInt16`, `error redefinition of OSWriteSwapInt32` and `error redefinition of OSWriteSwapInt64`.

Comment: See the [gist](https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/0f53eddef241394f58b7) for complete output

Comment: @user10000100_u: I will take a look at it tomorrow or the following day.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to describe what I tried precisely, and added a new gist containing all outputs.

Comment: @user10000100_u: You can't build for iOS on Linux (unless you are using a cross compiler). You must build cctools-port either on the device itself or on Mac OS X. You do not need to install LLVM etc. on the host OS. Install automake, autogen and libtool via macports.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, this explains it... Ok then, will use macports for libtool then (built from source the others already.) One point if you may know ? I say that there were issue with =>O2 optimization falgs and ld64. Is this happening for cydia's cctools package also or only for the cctools port from Thomas Pöchtrager ?

Comment: @user10000100_u: "Thomas Pöchtrager" is me :). I had issues with arm7 (coolstar too, btw.). Try `-O0` or `-O1` if you end up with a crashing linker.

Comment: Ah ah ;-) Wanted to ask, but didn't as I felt it intrusive. Well, nice to meet then, and thx for so much help.

Comment: Ok, I found `libtool` on gnu ftp, built it from source, and followed your instructions for build cctools : `export CC="clang -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=8.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk"` then `export CXX="clang++ -arch arm64 -mios-version-min=8.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk"` then `./configure -v --host=arm-apple-darwin11 --prefix=/usr/local/lvm-cross/cctools-arm64-port` then `make` and `sudo make install`...

Comment: ... The complete output is in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/9d4d718d182bfa74e163) Then on my iDevice I uninstalled cctools and ld64 cydia packages, put cctools somewhere, put its path in PATH, and tried to compile a simple hello world, and had errors. Verbose compilation is in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/MisesEnForce/8a73cd2f3135e41ffa41)

Comment: At some point I should have done the `unset CC CXX` before doing `make` but I had then the same kind of errors.

Comment: @user10000100_u: Ugh, have you tried `-O0` (via `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`)?

Comment: No. When using `clang++` you mean ? Or in the `export CC` and `export CXX` for the `configure` ?

Comment: @user10000100_u: When configuring cctools/ld64.

Comment: No confirmed then. Will try to add `export CFLAGS="-O0"` and `export CXXFLAGS="-O0"` before `configure`. Btw, should I unset `CC`, `CXX`, `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` after `configure` and before `make` ?

Comment: Tried with `-O1` and `-O0`, same result.

Comment: @user10000100_u: I can't debug it b/c I do not own an arm64 device. `org.coolstar.ld64` is compiled with `-arch armv7`, I think - so try with `-arch armv7`.

Comment: Bingo ! It worked. ;-) I am nevertheless really puzzled : `armv7` working on `arm64` for an iPad mini 3 which has an apple a7 processor whose `arch` is supposed to be `armv8-a`. Are all these `arch`'s the same ? Are at least `armv7` and `arm64` the same ? I guess they aren't, but they seem to be the same "linking wise".

Comment: @user10000100_u: You can of course run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit processor. I doesn't really matter what architecture the linker is compiled for.

Comment: so you say that a linker compiled for a 32-bits architecture will work on the 64-bits one, and will not have problem to do its job for 64-bits code. Ok then. Fair enough.

Comment: @user10000100_u Exactly. You could even link Mac OS X binaries with it.